# What are the environmental variables required to run RIDE with robotframework on Mac El Capitan

Tags: python, macos, robotframework

I am able to install RIDE on Windows but there is problem running on Mac. I have successfully install robotframework 3.0, Python 2.7(by default on Mac). I'm not sure how to install the Intellibot plugin on Mac for RIDE (It was required on Windows). I have followed the steps give on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33134896/install-wxpython-2-8-for-ride-on-osx-el-capitan) (2nd answer which has Xcode and wxmac formula)

I am able to successfully reach until the last step and verified using the import wx command. I didn't encountered any errors. I think it must be the environment variables which is creating a problem. I checked the ride.py location which is in the bin folder of python2.7. When I try to run the RIDE using the command ride.py then the error says:

> command not found

Comment: Are you literally typing the command `ride.py`? Or are you doing `python ride.py`, or something else?

Comment: @BryanOakley - I used both. When I used python ride.py then error says   [ERROR 2] can't open the file 'ride.py' No such file or directory.

Comment: Still not able to run the RIDE on Mac. I used the absolute path on terminal `python /Users/el/Library/Python/2.7/bin/ride.py` and the error was: Traceback (most recent call last):
 `File "/Users/el/Library/Python/2.7/bin/ride.py", line 20, in <module>
   from robotide import main
 File "/Users/el/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/robotide/__init__.py", line 37
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file /Users/el/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/robotide/__init__.py on line 37, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details`